# Hadoop C++ Pipes, SocketException: Broken pipe

Tags: c++, apache, hadoop, socketexception, broken-pipe

I am running a Hadoop Pipes job on Ubuntu 12.04 but am getting a Broken Pipe error when the reducer kicks in:

2013-04-17 10:40:38,088 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: Merging 0 segments, 0 bytes from memory into reduce
2013-04-17 10:40:38,088 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
2013-04-17 10:40:38,088 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 1795675 bytes
2013-04-17 10:40:38,118 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.PipesReducer: starting application
2013-04-17 10:40:38,264 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.PipesReducer: waiting for finish
2013-04-17 10:40:38,265 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.BinaryProtocol: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readVLong(WritableUtils.java:299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readVInt(WritableUtils.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.BinaryProtocol$UplinkReaderThread.run(BinaryProtocol.java:121)

2013-04-17 10:40:38,265 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Application: Aborting because of java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.